# How to specify what property a JavaFX ListView should display when using a custom object?

Tags: listview, user-interface, javafx

I've defined a ListView in my FXML file that will hold MyCustomData objects. The only way I can figure out how to tell it which property of MyCustomData to display is to add the following code to my controller:

```
myList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<MyCustomData>, ListCell<MyCustomData>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<MyCustomData> call(ListView<MyCustomData> param) {
        return new ListCell<MyCustomData>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(MyCustomData item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(item != null) {
                    setText(item.getMyProperty());
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

It sure would be nice to replace all of this messy code with a one-liner in the FXML that specifies the property that should be displayed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

First note that your cell implementation has a bug. You *must* deal with all possibilities in the `updateItem(...)` method. In your implementation, if the cell currently displays an item, and is then reused as an empty cell (e.g. if items are deleted), then the cell will not clear its text.

You can significantly reduce the amount of code if you implement the `Callback` as a lambda expression, instead of an anonymous inner class:

```
myList.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<MyCustomData>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyCustomData item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item == null ? null : item.getMyProperty() );
    }
});
```

If you are doing a lot of this, and want to reduce the amount of code still further, it's not hard to create a general reusable cell factory implementation:

```
public class ListViewPropertyCellFactory<T> 
    implements Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> {

    private final Function<T, String> property ;

    public ListViewPropertyCellFactory(Function<T, String> property) {
        this.property = property ;
    }

    @Override
    public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> listView) {
        return new ListCell<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, boolean);
                setText(item == null ? null : property.apply(item));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

which you could use with

```
myList.setCellFactory(new ListViewPropertyCellFactory<>(MyCustomData::getMyProperty));
```

If you prefer a more functional style to creating a class that implements `Callback`, you could similarly do

```
public class ListViewPropertyCellFactory {

    public static <T> Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> of(Function<T, String> property) {
        return lv -> new ListCell<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, boolean) ;
                setText(item == null ? null : property.apply(item));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and

```
myList.setCellFactory(ListViewPropertyCellFactory.of(MyCustomData::getMyProperty));
```